# MYSQL Select random from two rows

Tags: mysql, select, random

Can someone help me with this query.
I have this table for sample:

FILE Table

- UID
- file
- uploaded_on_date
- view_count

What I want to consider is the **top 30 most recent uploaded** file and **top 30 most viewed** file then **randomly select** from them and **limit by 10**.

I am new to this mysql complex queries. A sample query would be good and i will be able to understand it.
Thanks.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` type solutions will be very slow when the number of rows starts growing, just google for `order by rand slow`. Of course you won't notice this when selecting from 2*30 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
(
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tablefile
ORDER BY
  uploaded_on_date DESC
LIMIT 30
UNION SELECT
 *
FROM
  tablefile
ORDER BY
  view_count DESC
LIMIT 30
)
ORDER BY 
   RAND()
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply vulkanino and xdazz, really close time answered very awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
    select * from table order by upload_on_date desc limit 30
    union
    select * from table order by view_count desc limit 30) t 
order by rand() limit 10
```

Comment: oh my, exactly the same answer!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply vulkanino and xdazz, really close time answered very awesome.